# Linkify textView in Listview with setMultiChoiceModeListener not working?

Tags: android, android-layout

I used Listview with **setMultiChoiceModeListener** and apply Linkify on textview in Adapter. TextView becomes Linkify but Multichoicemode stop working.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Please edit your question and and relevant code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example